# Create trigger that deletes rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure

So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders_rows (
  order_id       NUMBER(10)   PRIMARY KEY,
  row_num        DATE  NOT NULL,
  p_id           NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
  quantity       NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
);
```

And I want to create a trigger that when update changes quantity to be 0 (zero)  -> delete this row.

I tried this:

> ***CHECK_ORDER_ROW trigger:***

```
create or replace
TRIGGER check_order_row
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on orders_rows
  for each row
BEGIN
  if :new.quantity = 0 then
  DELETE_ORDER_ROW(:new.order_id, :new.row_num);
  end if;
END;
```

DELETE_ORDER_ROW is the procedure:

> ***DELETE_ORDER_ROW procedure:***

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE delete_order_row (p_order_id NUMBER, p_row_num NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE orders_rows WHERE (order_id = p_order_id and row_num = p_row_num);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

But when I try to update:

```
update orders_rows set quantity=0 where (order_id=1 and row_num=1);
```

I get error:

```
A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
```

Any changes I can do? Or try other options to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's recursive trigger you are talking about. don't think Oracle supports one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't (or at least you shouldn't).

A row-level trigger on a table cannot generally query that same table without causing a mutating table exception.  If you were really determined, you could create a package, create a collection of `order_id` values in that package, create a before statement trigger that initializes the collection, create a row-level trigger that populated the collection with the `:new.order_id`, and then an after statement trigger that iterated through the collection and called `delete_order_row`.  That, however, is a lot of moving pieces to deal with.  It would generally make much more sense for the application code that is setting the `quantity` to 0 to delete the row instead.  Putting logic into a trigger that deletes a row that an application just inserted (or updated) generally leads to application flows that are very difficult to follow (in part because you can never see the entire flow at once, you're constantly looking to see what side-effects triggers are creating) and bugs that are very difficult to understand and debug.

If you're determined to use a trigger and you don't want to go with the three-trigger solution, you could also rename the table, create a view named `order_row` and create an `instead of` trigger on the view that turned an `update` on the view into an `update` or a `delete` on the base table depending on the `quantity` value.  That's adding an extra layer of indirection to your code, though, and it still tends to make application flows difficult to follow.

Comment: I was wondering if deleting a row when `quantity` reach 0 wouldn't conflict with concurrent updates  of the same row ? It feels to me like a race condition.

Comment: I don't see a race condition.  The session doing the update has to lock the row before the update can happen.  That same session should be able to delete the row without acquiring any additional locks and no other session could modify the row in the interim given that the trigger has to fire in the same transactional context as the `update`.  You could create a threading issue by doing something like issuing the delete from a trigger that was defined as an autonomous transaction.  But that would be a very poor idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if the OP has two simultaneous queries, one to decrease the quantity potentially down to 0, the other one to increase the quantity -- depending the order they are processed, both could succeed if the _increase_ is processed first (quantity `N` -> `N+M` -> `M`). _Or_, if the update to increase is processed after the decrease, it will fail as the row is deleted (quantity `N` -> `0` -- delete the row so could not _update_ it after that). Is this reasoning valid, or do I missed something here?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - You can't really have simultaneous queries updating the same row-- one session will acquire a lock and make its change first while the other blocks.  In a multi-user system, there is always the potential that some other session has locked the row you want to update or that the row has changed between the time you select it and the time that you modify it.  Adding a delete or a trigger to one session doesn't change that meaningfully.

Comment: Thank you very much @JustinCave helped me a lot! I hoped that delete from Oracle would be easier but I guess I'll just do it from my php code before the updating.:)